# iOS7 Bug? - Open in Maps app fails 50% of the time

Tags: ios, safari, ios7, mobile-safari, custom-url

I'm seeing what appears to be a bug with the way that map links (and apparently **all** custom URLs) are handled in iOS7. I'd like to know if anyone else is seeing it.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to Safari
- Type "maps.apple.com/?q=34.12345,-118.12345" in the address bar
- Select All -> Copy the text for further testing.
- Click "Go"

One of two things will happen:

A. You'll be immediately taken to the Apple Maps app and the lat/lon will display with a pin.

or

B. You'll receive a dialog asking if you'd like to open the link in "Maps," with options of "OK" or "Cancel." Clicking "OK" will do nothing, and you'll be left sitting at a blank Safari window.

The behavior seems to oscillate between these two conditions (A,B,A,B,...). Trying doing the steps again (pasting the exact link you saved earlier) and let me know if the same thing is happening for you.

Oddly, the same thing happens if you use the "comgooglemaps://?q=34.12345,-118.12345" equivalent for Google Maps.  Confirmed it fails as well with the "maps://" custom URL.  I've also seen this type of behavior when launching the links from the Messages app.

I don't know if it will work this way in native iOS apps, but this is what I'm seeing when I try to send users an SMS which includes a map link.
I ran the scenario on 2 iOS7 phones and the same thing happens on each of them. However, and **iOS6 iPad performs as expected**, launching the Maps app every time.

NOTE: I tried submitting it as a bug to Apple, but I'm run in circles between a broken website that refers me to an email address, and an auto-reply that refers me to a broken website.

Comment: Does the same for me for iOS 7 on an iPad 2.  However, this question is a bit off topic since it's not really related to a programming issue.

Comment: I see.  I guess I wanted confirmation that it wasn't just something I was doing wrong (such as formatting the the custom URLs incorrectly).

Comment: By the way, https://bugreport.apple.com is working just fine for me now, so you might want to try submitting a bug report again.

Comment: Still broken for me, but I'll check it periodically. Thanks!